# Media carousel in mobile view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have this code that will display image carousel.

For desktops, I want to display 3 thumbnails per row;
For mobiles, just one or two thumbnail per row horizontally.

The code in working fine in desktopview but in mobileview how do i display in horizontally with only one or two image and use the indicator to see next image ?

i tried using this..but is not working

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
```

[image: dektopview]

[image: mobileview]

html

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <h2>Media Slider Carousel BS3</h2>
      </div>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-8'>
          <div class="carousel slide media-carousel" id="media">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item  active">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
                  </div>          
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
                  </div>        
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
                  </div>          
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
                  </div>        
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
                  </div>          
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
                  </div>      
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a data-slide="prev" href="#media" class="left carousel-control">‹</a>
            <a data-slide="next" href="#media" class="right carousel-control">›</a>
          </div>                          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
 /* carousel */
    .media-carousel 
    {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      padding: 0 40px 30px 40px;
      margin-top: 30px;
    }
    /* Previous button  */
    .media-carousel .carousel-control.left 
    {
      left: -12px;
      background-image: none;
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
      border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 23px 23px 23px 23px;
      height: 40px;
      width : 40px;
      margin-top: 30px
    }
    /* Next button  */
    .media-carousel .carousel-control.right 
    {
      right: -12px !important;
      background-image: none;
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #222222;
      border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 23px 23px 23px 23px;
      height: 40px;
      width : 40px;
      margin-top: 30px
    }
    /* Changes the position of the indicators */
    .media-carousel .carousel-indicators 
    {
      right: 50%;
      top: auto;
      bottom: 0px;
      margin-right: -19px;
    }
    /* Changes the colour of the indicators */
    .media-carousel .carousel-indicators li 
    {
      background: #c0c0c0;
    }
    .media-carousel .carousel-indicators .active 
    {
      background: #333333;
    }
    .media-carousel img
    {
      width: 250px;
      height: 100px
    }
    /* End carousel */
```

js

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#media').carousel({
        pause: true,
        interval: false,
      });
    });
```

Comment: Basically you need a carousel which knows grouping. Slick is the first one coming to mind, but feel free to (re)search for more. You just place all elements as siblings and tell the carousel when and how to group them into one slide.